# How to handle img src if connection is not connected or disconnected when downloading - Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Assalamualaikum,

Hi everyone. i have problem when i display image in my nativescript angular app.
I did display image from downloadURL from firebase storage. but i got error if not connected.

here is my code in my daftar-toko.component.ts

```
<CardView class="cardStyle" margin="10" elevation="40" radius="1">
    <GridLayout rows="10,30,30,250, auto, auto,10" columns="10,40, *, 30,10">
        <Image [src]="toko.store.photo !=== ''? toko.store.photo : 'res://menu'" stretch="aspectFit" colSpan="3" col="1"
            row="3"></Image>
        <Label horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="toko.store.storeName" colSpan="3" row="4" textWrap="true" col="1"></Label>
        <Label horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="toko.store.noTelp" textWrap="true" col="1" row="5" colSpan="3"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</CardView>
```

the variabel toko.store.photo is contain downloadURL image from firebase storage.

and i got this error.
`Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firebasestorage.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname`

Any better ways to handle this connected and disconnected download image in Nativescript Angular?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but i would also add a cache on the Image, perhaps with `nativescript-image-cache-it` package.

Comment: As @VinceLowe mentioned, You could use `nativescript-image-cache-it` plugin which supports place holder / error image configurations.